# How to feed my network with the correct array size in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have the following code and I am trying to train the network that I built with Belgian traffic signs , here is the code below :

```
    import tensorflow as tf
import os 
import skimage.io
from skimage import transform 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)
#config_soft = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement =True)

def load_data(data_directory):
    directories = [d for d in os.listdir(data_directory) 
                   if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_directory, d))]
    labels = []
    images = []
    for d in directories:
        label_directory = os.path.join(data_directory, d)
        file_names = [os.path.join(label_directory, f) 
                      for f in os.listdir(label_directory) 
                      if f.endswith(".ppm")]
        for f in file_names:
            images.append(skimage.io.imread(f))
            labels.append(int(d))
    return images, labels

Root_Path = "/home/raed/Dropbox/Thesis/Codes/Tensorflow"
training_Directory = os.path.join(Root_Path,"Training")
testing_Directory = os.path.join(Root_Path,"Testing")
images, labels = load_data(training_Directory)

# Convert lists to array in order to retrieve to facilitate information retrieval 
images_array = np.asarray(images)
labels_array = np.asanyarray(labels)

#print some information about the datasets 
print(images_array.ndim)
print(images_array.size)
print(labels_array.ndim)
print(labels_array.nbytes)
print(len(labels_array))

# plotting the distribution of different signs
sns.set(palette="deep") 
plt.hist(labels,62)

# Selecting couple of images based on their indices 
traffic_signs = [300,2250,3650,4000]
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.imshow(images_array[traffic_signs[i]])
plt.show()

# Fill out the subplots with the random images and add shape, min and max values
for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1,4,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images_array[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    print("Shape:{0},max:{1}, min:{2}".format(images_array[traffic_signs[i]].shape,
                                              images_array[traffic_signs[i]].max(),
                                              images_array[traffic_signs[i]].min()))

# Get unique labels
unique_labels = set(labels_array)

# initialize the figure
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))

i=1
for label in unique_labels:
    image = images_array[labels.index(label)]
    plt.subplot(8,8,i)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.title('label:{0} ({1})'.format(label, labels.count(label)))
    i=i+1
    plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in images]
images28_array = np.asanyarray(images28)

for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1,4,i+1)
    plt.imshow(images_array[traffic_signs[i]])
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    print("Shape:{0},max:{1}, min:{2}".format(images28_array[i].shape,
                                              images28_array[i].max(),
                                              images28_array[i].min()))

#convert to grayscale
gray_images = skimage.color.rgb2gray(images28_array)

for i in range(len(traffic_signs)):
    plt.subplot(1, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(gray_images[traffic_signs[i]], cmap="gray")
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5)

# Show the plot
plt.show()

# prepare placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape =[None, 28,28])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype= tf.int32, shape=[None])

#Flatten the input data
images_flat = tf.layers.flatten(x)

#Fully connected layer , Multi-layer Perceptron (MLP)
logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(images_flat,62, tf.nn.relu)

#Define loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=y, logits=logits))

#define an optimizer (Stochastic Gradient Descent )
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss)

#convert logits to label indices
correct_prediction = tf.arg_max(logits,1)

#define an accuracy metric
accuracy =tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

#########################################
print('######### Main Program #########')  
#########################################
print("images_flat: ", images_flat)
print("logits: ", logits)
print("loss: ", loss)
print("Optimizer:",optimizer)
print("predicted_labels: ", correct_prediction)

tf.set_random_seed(1235)
#images28 = np.asanyarray(images28).reshape(-1, 28, 28,1)

#with tf.Session() as training_session:
#    training_session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
#    for i in range(201):
#        print('Epoch', i)
#        _,accuracy_value = training_session([optimizer, accuracy],feed_dict={x:images28, y:labels})
#        if i%10 ==0:
#            print("Loss", loss)
#        print('Epochs Done!!')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(201):
        _, loss_value = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict={x: gray_images, y: labels})
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print("Loss: ", loss)
```

I also did a series of transformation before feeding the netwok as follows :

```
images28 = [transform.resize(image, (28, 28)) for image in images]
images28_array = np.asanyarray(images28)
```

But on execution I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (4575, 28, 28, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder_189:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28)'
```

Could you please help me , where am I doing wrong in training this network, please refer to the following link for more information:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/tensorflow-tutorial

Comment: You feed 4575 images, each with shape 28x28x3 (the last "3" is likely for 3 color channels: red, green and blue, but the placeholder of the model expects elements of shape 28x28 (1 channel). You should either change what your model expects as inputs (i.e. change placeholder shape) or change what you actually input (i.e. reduce dimensionalilty of images if it makes sense, e.g. by making them monochrome, like in your tutorial).

Comment: can you help me explicitly with that , I tried to add a 3 to my placeholder but that generated another error

Comment: I will put my full code for more information , I already transformed my images to gray-scale just like the tutorials